# How to have sort of both flex-grow and justify-content: space-between

Tags: html, css, flexbox

i havent found questions covering the exact issue im facing. ive only found conversations about respective parts of my problem - which id be able to solve - but not about the exact thing im trying to.

im having a horizontal menu as a list; elements' count and content can easily change:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <ul id="menu">
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>another item</li>
    <li>an even longer item</li>
    <li>last item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

having this condition:

```
#wrapper{
  width: 940px;
}
```

now, i need the li elements to:

- be horizontally aligned
- catch the full available width of #wrapper while corresponding to the length of their respective content
- have their text content centered, while having it left aligned for the first, e.g. right aligned for the last element, plus having equal spaces between all the text elements

here is a sketch of the layout:

[layout sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLD5w.png)

the orange bar is the #wrapper containing the `<ul>`. the blue and green lines indicate the widths of the children `<li>` elements. as you can see, the `<li>` take their width from the length of the contained texts. and there are equal spaces between the texts, while still having the first text aligned to the left and the last aligned to the right.

hence i need this:

```
----------------------------- wrapper -----------------------------
------------------------------- ul --------------------------------
-- li --- ------- li ------- ----------- li ---------- ---- li ----
item 1   |   another item   |   an even longer item   |   last item
```

i know i could use `justify-content: space-between` for the li elements, but then they would not occupy the entire available space of #wrapper anymore, but would just cover their text content.

if i used `flex-grow: 1`, though, the full width would be taken, but the text contents of the elements would then not be aligned to the space between anymore.

anyone got an idea how to approach this?

any hints are appreciated!

cheers,

thomas

Comment: have right margin for the first element and left margin for the last element

Comment: the margins depend on the number and length of the elements, though. i cant have fix margins here. the spaces between the elements need to be equal.

Comment: I think what you want to do is impossible. On the one hand the space between the texts is equal and while the `li` occupy all available space.  `justify-content: space-between` property is calculated considering the content of the `li`, you can't then change the size of `li` maintaining that calculation

Comment: ja, im actually also pretty afraid its impossible without javascript. the js solution would either be to go for justify-content: space-between and then use js to draw the occupying boxes as absolute divs. or i would go for flex-grow 1 with centered texts and would then use js to have the <ul> exceed the #wrapper on the left and right in a way where the texts would then start/end just at the wrappers left/right border..

Answer (score 0):

If u need aling the first to the left and the last to the rigth you can use this:

```
li:first-child{text-align: left;}
li:last-child{text-align: right;}
```

And you can use [this](https://jsfiddle.net/y30txLmv/3/)?

Comment: hi there, thank you! same as for michaels answer, though: the space between e.g. the first and the second element would be bigger than the space between the second and the third.

Comment: ive just seen your jsfiddle. unfortunately thats neither working for me as in your example the <li> items dont take the entire available space of the <ul>. thats the problem with justify-content: space-between

Comment: naja, lets just stick with your fiddle. what im looking for now would be your fiddle - just that one should not be able to see the red background of the <ul> anymore. everything should be blue, plus having the texts aligned to the borders on the left and right respectively.

Comment: check now, i think now is what you need

Comment: naja, thats the approach with the text-align left/center/right. now we have the problem that the spaces between the text elements are not the same: the space between the first and the second element is bigger than the space between the second and the third.. im wondering whether there might be a way with having the <ul> exceed the #wrapper on the left and right respectively and then having an overflow: hidden cutting the <ul> just at the left/right of the respective first/last <li> elements. but its very vague as i have no clue how to position the <ul> without javascript.